# Get the selected label value for inputSelect

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to return the label value of the selected option using an inputSelect?

`<ui:inputSelect label="Staff Package: " class="dynamic" aura:id="staffPackageInputSelect" change="{!c.onStaffPackageSelect}"/>`

Controller:

```
onStaffPackageSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getSelectedFilteredPicklistOption(component,event);
}
```

Helper:

```
getSelectedFilteredPicklistOption: function(component, event) {
    var selectedItem = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    component.set("v.selectedFieldValue", selectedItem);
}
```

I've got the value, but I also need to get the selected label value.

Comment: Components from `ui` namespace are deprecated from Winter 2021. You should consider using the lightning ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To resolve my issue, I concatenated the label to the value using a separator and then parsed out each value using string methods: `substringAfter(delimiter)` and 'substringBefore(delimiter)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the options are dynamically populated *[something like this in the controller init method: `cmp.find("staffPackageInputSelect").set("v.options", <Options (Object array here)>);`]*, then in the method `getSelectedFilteredPicklistOption` you can find the selected option's label using the following snippet:

```
event.getSource().get("v.options").filter(entry => entry.selected == true)[0].label;
```

---

If the options are populated statically in the component HTML file, then you can use the following snippet:

```
Object.entries(event.getSource().get("v.body")).filter(entry => entry[1].get("v.value") == true)[0][1].get("v.label");
```

Note that you cannot get the options (*object array*) using `v.options` (*unlike the case of dynamic binding*) and hence, you need to use `v.body` to get the all the `ui:inputSelectOption` elements within and then filter the nested object arrays to locate the option selected.